# Best method for importing csv or excel file to SQL Server 2005 using .net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, excel, csv

I'm looking for the best method for importing csv or excel file to SQL Server 2005 using .net MVC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a really good library called [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) which is a) 100% free, b) fully in C#, and it can easily import any kind of text-based file - comma-separated, tab-separated, fixed width and so on.

You should have no trouble using this to load your CSV file into in-memory objects and storing those in SQL Server using ADO.NET.

In FileHelpers, you first need to have a class that describes your data, e.g. a "Customer" class (or whatever it is you're importing).

Then, you can import a file using code something like this:

```
FileHelperEngine<Customer> engine = new FileHelperEngine<Customer>();
Customer[] dataLoaded = engine.ReadFile(fileName);
```

Once you have your array of customers, you can either just iterate through that and save the data (typically inside a transaction) with e.g. a stored procedure or a ad-hoc SQL query:

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
   foreach(Customer c in dataLoadad)
   {
      SaveCustomer(c);
   }

   ts.Complete();
}
```

or you could convert the customer array to a DataTable and use SqlBulkCopy to bulk insert that into your SQL Server database - there are lots of options!

**UPDATE:**
Do you have a `[DelimitedRecord]` or another of those attributes on your `BlackListDevice` class?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I had a look at the file helper. I'm using ActiveRecord and NHibernate. 

I get this error 
The record class don't have records.

on this line 
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(BlackListDevice));

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yeah, my class looks like this 

[DelimitedRecord(" ")] 
    [ActiveRecord]
    public class BlackListDevice: Identified
    {

        [Property]
        public virtual string DeviceReference { get; set; }

    }

Comment: And when do you get this error? When compiling? when running? Does your file really contain any data, and does it contain data that matches your record structure?

Comment: Is this really advisable if you have say 1,000,000 records or more?

Comment: No, if you have that many records, I'd probably find a way to use one of the bulk copy methods. But that's rare - typically, you have a couple hundred or couple thousand at most - for those 80-90% cases, FileHelpers works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding a seperate class for file uploads, works like a charm using the FileHelper.